# How does changing the $j$th eigenvalue of $A$ affects another matrix represented in the same basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Suppose $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Then there exists a basis transformation matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = D$ is a diagonal matrix. Now let $B$ be another symmetric matrix. The matrix $X = P^{-1}BP$ is represented in the same basis that makes $A$ a diagonal matrix (but $X$ may not be a diagonal matrix).

Assuming $D$ has $n$ elements, so it makes sense to talk about dimension $1,2,3,..n$. How can I identify the $j$th dimension of $D$ in $X$? I want to decide whether a dimension (in $D$) is relevant based on thresholding the eigenvalue.

So if, for example, the $n$th eigenvalue is below a threshold I set it to zero and I want to identify the same dimension in $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the last diagonal element of $D$, say $\mu_n$ to $0$, then the matrix $A$ has to change, but $P$ does not.
You can see that by writing $A=\sum_{k=1}^l \lambda_k \pi_k$, where $\lambda_k$ is the $k-$th eigenvalue (without multiplicity), $\pi_k$ is the projection onto the $k-$th eigenspace (and $\mu_k$ would be the $k-$th eigenvalue while counting multiplicity).

Hence you can change $\mu_n$ but keep the eigenspaces, and thus $P$, unchanged. So there is more for you to choose to get an answer to your initial question.

Comment: True, I did not think about that. So let me rephrase the question: Assuming $D$ has $n$ elements, so it makes sense to talk about dimension $1,2,3,..n$. What I want to do is to identify the $j$th dimension of $D$ in $X$.

Comment: Let me be more specific. A linear map is fully determined by two things: its eigenvalues and its corresponding eigenspaces. The basis transformation matrix P is only depending on the eigenspaces (and the initial basis) while the diagonal matrix D is only depending on the eigenvalues (and the initial basis).
The fact that this fully determines $A$ can be seen by writing $A=PDP^{-1}$. So if I understand your question correctly, the basis transformation matrix $P$ remains stable, if you only change the $j$th entry in $D$. Hence $X$ is represented in the same eigenbasis as before.